# Tracing changes made in Jenkins global configuration

Tags: jenkins

Can I trace changes made in the global configuration of Jenkins to be able to retrieve the users who did the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Audit Trail Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Audit+Trail+Plugin) tracks who is

> creating/configuring/deleting jobs and views or delete/save-forever/start a build

If you are looking for something that tracks changes made under the Manage Jenkins section (ex. Configure System page or Add Plugins), I don't know of anything right off hand that tracks those change.

In our system, we severely limit who can access the Manage Jenkins section, or Job configuration, for that matter, so tracking changes is a less of an issue. Having as few administrators as possible might solve your issue. In our system, we do allow users to add certain types of jobs manually or perform certain administration / configuration tasks, but we do this by way of other jobs which control exactly how things are set up. In this way, we can easily track who added the job, ran the build, etc.

Comment: I found a solution. [JobConfigHistory Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JobConfigHistory+Plugin) does the job.